# The Cauchy Principal value of a rational function with only real poles

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

$\newcommand{\PV}{\operatorname{P.V.}}$I have a doubt about the Cauchy Principal Value of real rational functions.

$f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a rational function with $\deg(\text{denominator})>\deg(\text{numerator})$.

$\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \} \subset \mathbb{R} $ is the  set of all $f$ poles

$\PV$ exists and it is

$$\PV \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \ dx=\pi i \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{Res}(f,x_k) \right) $$

$$\pi i \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{Res}(f,x_k) \right) \in \mathbb{I}$$

So: $$\PV \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \ dx=0$$
because:
$$\operatorname{Re} \left( \pi i \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{Res}(f,x_k) \right) \right)=0$$

Is it true?

$\PV \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \ dx$ doesn't exist if $\deg(\text{numerator}) \ge \deg(\text{denominator})$, does it?

In general, which are the conditions of existence of P V?

Is it correct?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't require all poles to be simple, the principal value of the integral need not exist, consider $f(x) = \dfrac{x+1}{x^2(x-1)}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer , I have done these calculations:

$\frac{x+1}{x^2 (x-1)}=\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{-2}{x}+\frac{3}{x-1}$ 

$\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{1}{x^2}=\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} -\frac{2}{R}=0$ 

$\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{-2}{x}=0$ (odd function)
 
$\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{3}{x-1}=\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} 3 \ln \rvert \frac{R-1}{-R-1} \rvert=0$  

Is there any mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Daniel Fischer** already notes in the comments that some condition must be
imposed on $f$ to assure that the principal value exists.
For example, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx/x^2 = \infty$, principal value or no:
the integrand is positive, so there's no cancellation when we remove
small symmetrical neighborhoods of the pole at $x=0$.

Assume that the poles of $f$ are simple.  Then the argument that OP 
**Francesco Serie** gave is essentially correct, though one must
include the pole at infinity if the difference between the 
denominator's and numerator's degree is only $1$ (because the 
*differential* $f(x)\,dx$ then has a simple pole at infinity).
Indeed it is known that for *any* rational function $f \in {\bf C}(x)$
the sum of the residues of $f(x)\,dx$ at all its poles on the Riemann sphere
vanishes.

A simpler argument is to expand $f$ in partial fractions.  Under our 
hypothesis, $f$ is an $\bf R$-linear combination of the functions
$1/(x-x_k)$; the principal-value integral is a linear map to $\bf R$, 
and it is elementary that the principal value of each
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx/(x-x_k)$ is zero, so the same is true of
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx$.

This also suggests the generalization to functions that might have
multiple roots: the principal-value integral exists **iff**
$f$ is a linear combination of functions $1/(x-x_k)^{e_k}$ with
each $e_k$ odd, and then the P.V. integral again equals zero.