Evaluate the integral $\text{P.V.} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{(x-a)^{n_1} (x-b)^{n_2}} dx$
Consider the principal value integral:
$$\text{P.V.} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{(x-a)^{n_1} (x-b)^{n_2}}  dx$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, $n_1$ and $n_2$ are integers with $n_{1} \ge 2$ and $n_2 \ge 1$
Is it correct that this always diverges?
My reasoning is as follows: if we expand this into partial fractions, it seems that we can never express this in a way where all the fractions are of the form $c/(x-k)^n$ and n is odd. That is we cannot avoid the even power in the denominator.
For example,
$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^3
   (x-2)}=\frac{1}{-2+x}-\frac{1}{(-1+x)^3}-\frac{1}{(-1+x)^2}-\frac{1}{-1+x}$$
Here I do not see a way to avoid the fraction involving the even power: $\frac{1}{(-1+x)^2}$
If the even powers cannot be avoided, according to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2148257/1322804, it should diverge.
Thanks
